# Atom Text Editor Cannot save .htaccess on Windows

Tags: windows, .htaccess, atom-editor

I am getting the message:

> Unable to safe file: Permission Denied

every time I try to save changes to the `.htaccess` file on Windows (10).

I assume it has something to do with the fact that it’s a hidden file, but I can’t find a way around this.

How can I save changes to `.htaccess` ?

Comment: It this possibly the cause? "owner of the htaccess file was somehow changed from the server side, thats why the plugin was unable to write anything in it"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes can be solved by starting atom as administrator 
(***beware*** this will start atom with elevated privledges and you could potentially overwrite important system files if proper care is not taken!)

1. Right-click Atom shortcut-icon on your Desktop
2. Select '*Run as administrator*'